# Arranging items received over form fields into a grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am getting my list items in React by inputting them over 2 form fields. To style my list items(10 items) I am using external css file and CSS grid. My grid should look like a pyramid when finally output, but instead everything is being output in one column that has 10 rows. My styling for items is following:

```
.Task .container ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
        grid-row: 1 / 13;
        grid-column: 1 / 2
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
        grid-row: 1 / 7;
        grid-column:  2 / 3;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
        grid-row: 7 / 13;
        grid-column:  2 / 3;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
        grid-row: 1 / 5;
        grid-column:  3 / 4;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(5) {
        grid-row: 5 / 9;
        grid-column:  3 / 4;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(6) {
        grid-row: 9 / 13;
        grid-column:  3 / 4;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(7) {
        grid-row: 1 / 4;
        grid-column: 4 / 5;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(8) {
        grid-row: 4 / 7;
        grid-column: 4 / 5;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(9) {
        grid-row: 7 / 10;
        grid-column: 4 / 5;
    }

.Task .container ul li:nth-of-type(10) {
        grid-row: 10 / 13;
        grid-column: 4 / 5;
    }
```

When I check in code inspector, all these classes/styling are being applied, but instead of getting a pyramid I am getting single column with items arranged in rows.
My question is, is it possible to style items like this (that are received over form fields and external css file) in order to achieve the grid or this make no sense? Have you got any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: no, only css grid. In my project above this list i have also another list with ordinary data - ready data(not received over form fields), also styled with css grid, and with this the another pyramid looks ok. To be clear both lists has different css classes/styles, therefore there is no class interferation.